# Print number x number of times based on value of a cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have one column with a certain ID number an A1, and another number in B1.  How can I make a cell with A1 written as many times as the number in B1 (taking for granted the formula can be extrapolated downward.)

Answer (score 0):

You want to make use of the [REPT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/rept-HP005209236.aspx) function, like this:

```
      A      B
      ---    ---
1:    42     5
2:    =REPT(A1, B1)
```

This will output:

```
4242424242
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  Is there a way to make the output into a column? With each 42 being in a different row?  Like the choosing of 42, by the way :)

Comment: Maybe through the use of [OFFSET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324991) but I am not sure.

Comment: maybe use `=REPT(A1&CHAR(10),B1)` and set sell format to wrap

Answer (score 0):

In C1

```
=IF(ROW()<=$B$1,$A$1,"")
```

and copy down for the largest B1 you expect.  It will put whatever is in A1 in C1:C?.  It checks the row of the the cell that contains the formula, ROW(), against the number in B1.  If you're starting in a row other than row 1, you'll need to adjust.  For example, if you're starting in row 6

```
=IF(ROW()-5<=$B$6,$A$6,"")
```